# Facebook login not calling on login function after login is clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api, air, facebook-login

I am making a mobile app (Android and IOS) using adobe air and flash pro. This is my first attempt at using a facebook api. the problem (I think) I am having is the facebookMobile.login method is not returning anything after the login btn is pressed ie I am not getting the logged in or login failed trace message. if i was at least getting a login failure messagge at least i would know that the onLogin function was being called. Below is my as3 class

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.CameraUI;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.*;  
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.Sprite;

import com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile;
//import com.facebook.graph.windows;


public class Main extends MovieClip {

    private var logInBtn:LogIn = new LogIn();
    private var vidCon:Video = new Video();
    static const APP_ID:String = "1234512345";
    protected var extendedPermissions:Array = ["publish_stream","user_website","user_status","user_about_me"];

    public function Main() {
        // constructor code
        trace("main loaded");
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        FacebookMobile.init(APP_ID, onInit);
    }

    public function onInit(success:Object, fail:Object):void{
        if (success){ 
            trace("Already logged in");
        }
        else{
            trace("Not logged in");
            addChild(logInBtn);
            logInBtn.x = logInBtn.y =200;
            logInBtn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, logInbtnPressed);
        }
    }

    private function logInbtnPressed(e:TouchEvent){

        removeChild(logInBtn);
        FacebookMobile.login(onLogin,stage, extendedPermissions);
    }
    //--the below function dosnt seem to be getting called--
    public function onLogin(success:Object, fail:Object):void{
        if (success){
            trace("Logged In\n");
            loggedIn();
        }
        else{
            trace("Login Failed\n");
        }
    }

    public function onLogout(success:Boolean):void {
        trace("Log out");
    }
}
```

any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you set up everything on FB? Do you have a valid app id?

Comment: Yes i set up an app in sandbox mode. I changed the app id for posting here but have the correct one in my class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution i needed to add a web view to the facebookMobile.login call.

```
private var  webView = new StageWebView();
webView.stage = stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(10, 10, (stage.stageWidth -20), (stage.stageHeight - 20));
FacebookMobile.login( onLogin , this.stage, extendedPermissions, webView);
```